# PrimeNG Tree Checkbox show the checkboxes on the right side of nodes

Tags: checkbox, primeng

I need to show the checkboxes on the right side of each tree node. is possible to change the node label and checkbox distribution?

Answer (score 0):

I just got it works with custom styles:

```
.ui-treenode-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.ui-treenode-content .ui-treenode-label {
  flex: 1 ;
}

.ui-treenode-content .ui-chkbox {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```